# Initializing sails new with indent of 4?

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible to do a new sails app but have the indentation be 4 spaces? It seems it gets created with 2 spaces.

I am using sailsjs 1.0 - and currently I create app by doing:

1. sails new blah_name_here
2. Choose "Web App"